# How do you run as a different user from the Start Menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, runas

Running an application as a different user (e.g. domain admin account) from the start menu (by shift + right-clicking the application) used to be an option in Windows 7 & XP.

However, I can't find that option in Windows 10. The workaround seems to be either 1) to find the application in Windows Explorer (shift + right-click) or 2) use runas.exe from the command line.

However, in order to use those workarounds, I have look up the executable name first. It's a bit difficult because I don't have the name of every RSAT tool or executable name memorized.

(e.g. "Active Directory Users and Computers" is dsa.msc, "Routing and Remote Acces" is rrasmgmt.msc)

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

1. Open Registry Editor by pressing Windows + R key combination, type in `regedit` and press Enter. If prompted by UAC, click on Yes to continue.
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` - If you do not find this key, then right click and add the Explorer key under Windows and add DWORD value `ShowRunasDifferentuserinStart`
3. In right-side pane, right click on `ShowRunasDifferentuserinStart` key and then click Modify.
4. Enter `1` as the value in Value data box
5. Click Ok to save the setting.
6. Close Registry Editor. Restart the system.

After rebooting, you should have the "Run as different user option", sometimes under the "More" drop down.

I've done this on several domain joined and non domain joined PCs, works like a charm.

Source: [windows10update.com](http://www.windows10update.com/2015/08/windows-10-tutorials-170-show-run-as-different-user-on-start-menu-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Nice find. I comment both Moses and ThoAppelsin with this. I got the registry setting by following the config panel find by ThoAppelsin. So I _seem_ to be configured, but even after a reboot this thingy does not work. Perhaps there's some other setting (policy) that says 'if stupid user' (me) then don't allow Run-As anyway..?

Answer (score 6):

You just right click on the shortcut.

[image]

You can also create a shortcut and use "runas" same as any version of Windows as explained in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/124445/run-as-a-different-user-on-a-shortcut?rq=1) by [Chris Dwyer](https://superuser.com/users/11662/chris-dwyer)

> 1. Right-click > New > Shortcut
> 2. For Target, type "runas /user:ComputerName\administrator program.exe"
>
> .....
>
> [To create a shortcut using the runas command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_security_runas_shortcut.mspx?mfr=true)
>
> .....

You can also use [StartIsBack++](http://startisback.com/) to get the functionality again.

[image]

If a program like StartIsBack++ cannot be used you can enable the behavior with the by setting the Start Menu and Taskbar `Show "Run as different user" command on Start` group policy to **Enabled**

[image]

[image]

[Related - How to Add or Remove "Run as different user" on "Start" Application Bar in Windows 8 and 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9210-run-different-user-add-remove.html)

Comment: I did not downvote, but I do have improvement suggestions: Your answer (set the group policy option) is great and helped me (have an upvote for that), but (1) it is hidden below irrelevant stuff (how do I "run as administrator" - that was not the question) and a (unnecessary, as your group policy answer shows) third-party software recommendation. (2) The only way to find out *which* policy to set is by deciphering your scaled-down screenshot. My suggestion would be to start your answer from scratch, describe in simple steps how to set the group policy option. You can keep the screenshot, ...

Comment: ...but don't scale it and crop it to the relevant upper left-hand portion. Those other, mostly-empty screenshots don't add any value and make your answer harder to read. If you want to mention your alternative solutions as well, that's fine, but do that below your *actual* solution.

Comment: I removed information that could identify me.  I won’t be changing the screenshots.  Running as an Administrator, is potentially running an application, as another user.  I wrote out which policy to enable, my screenshot, is just a visual illustration.

Comment: You did not mention that it was under User Configuration/Administrative Templates - that can only be seen in the screenshot. About the other screenshots: Not problem, it's your answer - I only gave feedback because you explicitly asked for it (in a now deleted comment).

Answer (score 5):

There is another (probably new) solution to enable this functionality, which is far more simple than the other ones offered. Simply navigate to the *Settings* > *Update & security* > *For developers*, and under the *Windows Explorer* one can see a list of things that can be applied.

That list of things that you may apply, might be a little hard to understand at the first look, but I believe it works like this: If it is grayed-out, then it means that that particular thing is already like that (enabled), and hitting the *Apply* will enable the ones that are not grayed-out and are currently selected.

Following that description I've just made up, if one wants to enable just the *Change policy to show Run as different user in Start*, he/she has to remove the checks from all the others and hit the *Apply*.

And finally, here's a screenshot of the particular setting I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: Nice find. I comment both Moses and ThoAppelsin with this. I got the registry setting by following the config panel find by ThoAppelsin. So I _seem_ to be configured, but even after a reboot this thingy does not work. Perhaps there's some other setting (policy) that says 'if stupid user' (me) then don't allow Run-As anyway..?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Secondary Logon service (`seclogon`) is running, the following code blocks permit a combination of Batch and VBScript files to automate the task. the batch file uses relative path references to allow the files to be places into any path that allows at least read permission by the current and selected user accounts. Both files should be located within the same path. The use of `ShellExecute` with a verb of `runasuser` causes Windows to bring up a prompt to allow the user to select from any logon method allowed by the host computer.

This process can be added to a users startup processes so that it occurs once logged into a computer system.

Batch file: `{RunAsUser}{CMD}.cmd`

```
@Echo Off

If "%~1" NEQ "/CALLBACK" Goto :label_Process_Run_As_User

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM Start the process once running as designated user
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

cd C:\
start "" %~dp0cmd.lnk

Goto :EOF

:label_Process_Run_As_User

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM Section below verifies if Secondary Login is available
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

REM Query [Secondary Logon]
sc query seclogon 1> nul 2> nul || (
    Goto :label_Missing_Secondary_Login
)

REM Check to see if [Secondary Logon] service is not disabled
sc qc seclogon | Find /i "START_TYPE" | Find /i "DISABLED" 1> nul 2> nul && (
    Set flg.SecLog.Enabled=F
) || (
    Set flg.SecLog.Enabled=T
)

REM Check to see if [Secondary Logon] service is Running
sc queryex seclogon | Find /i "STATE" | Find /i "RUNNING" 1> nul 2> nul && (
    Set flg.SecLog.Running=T
) || (
    Set flg.SecLog.Running=F
)

REM Determine if action should work
If /i "%flg.SecLog.Enabled%:%flg.SecLog.Running%" EQU "F:F" Goto :label_Secondary_Login_Unavailable

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM Section below starts the RunAsUser process
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

REM System configuration was validateed and RunAsUser will commence

Set "str.SELF=%~0"

WSCRIPT /E:VBSCRIPT "%~dp0RunAsUser.txt"

Goto :EOF

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM Section below provides written notices to user for error conditions
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:label_Secondary_Login_Unavailable
Echo.
Echo Unable to utilize the Secondary Logon system service because it is disabled.
Echo.
pause
Goto :EOF

:label_Missing_Secondary_Login
Echo.
Echo Unable to find the Secondary Logon system service
Echo.
pause
Goto :EOF
```

VBScript file: `RunAsUser.txt`

```
'-------------------------------------------
'
' Launch Process RunAsUser
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("PROCESS")("str.SELF"), "/CALLBACK", "", "runasuser", 1
'
' Display a message box to pause script
msgbox "Enter username or select Certificate for account" & vbCrLf & "On the windows dialog that will popup." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Click OK once process opens", vbokonly
'
' Quit the script
On Error Resume Next
Window.Close ' HTA Must be Closed Through the Window Object
Err.Clear
Wscript.Quit ' VBS Must be Closed Through the Wscript Object
Err.Clear
On Error Goto 0
'
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```